# Is there any segulah for pain or injury?

Tags: segulah, injury

Is there any source that discusses a segulah for pain or injury such as chronic pain or unexplained pain?

Comment: You might want to look at the sefer סגולות אברהם Segulos Avraham, it is full of advices on segulos on different kinds of illnesses. For example, it describes that Chamomile tea is effective in treating inflammations.

Comment: Prayer and meticulous observance of Shulchan Oruch are well-known and proven segulos.

Comment: Especially the halacha of learning Torah :)

Answer (score 1):

There probally are alot of good segulos but i heard a amazing point from r ahron lopiansky that hashem will alot of times gives someone pain A- because of some sins they did B- to give you a challenge so you could rise above it and be better so theyre are segulos and some really based ones but try not to use it as a way out